# Android, how to lazy load images from url and persistently cache them in gallery widget?

Tags: android, image, caching, lazy-loading, gallery

I'm implementing an Android gallery widget.
I'm asking how to lazy (i.e. in a separate thread) load images from the web and persistently cache them? So that on the next run I have the cached images locally available...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Check the demo in the second answer, helped me massively!

Answer (score 5):

Try this code.the universal  imageloader.

> https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: This should be in comment!

Comment: And, the link is a 404 (probably it's https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this tutorial [Android: Help in adapting ListView adapter with an ImageLoader Class (LazyList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867894/android-help-in-adapting-listview-adapter-with-an-imageloader-class-lazylist)

Hope, it's helps you!.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You have to use Picasso. 

    it's easy to use

    downlod latest jar from  http://square.github.io/picasso/

    simply load image used below code

    Picasso.with(context)
               .load(url)
               .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
               .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
               .centerCrop()
               .into(image);
```