# How to set an image and text (like label) to a gridview through webservice in android

Tags: android

Iam trying to get the image and text in gridview.

These datas are retrived from webservice. I retrived the same but dont know how to set these datas in gridview!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to show image view and textview on the same cell of gridview

Create a viewHolder class and edit the `getView()` of your adapter as shown below

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = new View(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        vi = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(CategoryList.get(position).toString());
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        holder.image.setTag(R.drawable.arrow);
    }
    holder.text.setText(CategoryList.get(position).toString());
    holder.image.setTag(R.drawable.arrow);
    vi.setTag(holder);
    return vi;
}
```

Edit :

I also had the same issue i was getting image url from webservices and i wanted to show the images on listview : so i used following class to save images using hashset on sd card

```
public class CacheImages {

    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;

    final int stub_id = your.package.name.R.drawable.stub;

    PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

    CacheImages(Context context) {
        // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
        // the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

        // Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/data/projectname");
            //Log.v("cacheDir ", cacheDir + "");
        } else {
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        }
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                    // queue
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    //else{
                        if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                            synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                                photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                            }
                            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                            cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                            if ((photoToLoad.imageView.getTag())
                                    .equals(photoToLoad.url)) {
                                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                        photoToLoad.imageView);
                                Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                        .getContext();
                                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                            }
                        }
                    //}
                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
//      PhotoToLoad photoToLoad = new PhotoToLoad(url, new ImageView(a));
//      String filename = photoToLoad.url;
        //String filename = url;
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Log.v("TAG FILE :", filename);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        // Is the bitmap in our cache?
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
        if (bitmap != null)
            return bitmap;
        else {
            // Nope, have to download it
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url)
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
                // save bitmap to cache for later
                writeFile(bitmap, f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //Log.v("FILE NOT FOUND", "FILE NOT FOUND");
                return null;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        if (cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
        // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        // start thread if it's not started yet
        if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    // stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image) {
            for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
                if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
            bitmap = b;
            imageView = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        // clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        // clear SD cache
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }
}
```

and then to load the image from url i used following code to display image on listitem

```
holder.image.setTag(img.getImage(holder.image, Url));
```

Comment: Thanks Shruti.But i need to setText and setImage that is coming from webservice.

Comment: from webservice u r getting image url or image ??

Comment: url of an image and name of the label

Comment: eg: [15, Love, Images/CategoryImage/LoveIcon.JPG], like these set of text am gettimg..How can i set these text and imageurl to gridview except id

Comment: @kalai : see my edited answer may this help you now.see my question too here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103729/android-download-images-from-server-and-save-them-on-device-cache

Comment: :Thanks frnd..Actually i dont need to save the images,just to show it of to the gridview.In a gridview if the paticular image is clicked then it should be downloaded and to set it as a wallpaper

Comment: @ Sruthi: Thanks for the help..Finally i have completed but the image size differs in gridview.Is ther anyway to accomplish the same size for each image