# How can I take a Drawable that I got from the internet and save it to my Android device in a cache directory?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable, android-file

Here is my code... you'll see where I want to save the `Drawable d` into the `File f` location:

```
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.imvCover);
    File cacheDir = this.getCacheDir();
    File f = new File(cacheDir, itemDict.get("Barcode") + ".jpg");
    if (f.exists())
    {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    else
    {
        String url = (String)itemDict.get("imageURL");
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        if (d != null)
        {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(d);

            // TODO: save the drawable into the cache directory
        }
        else
        {
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cam);
        }
    }
```

How do I save the Drawable as a .jpg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Bitmap.compress(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29), like so:

```
try {
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/someLocation/someFileName.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
   //TODO: Handle exception
}
```

See this SO answer for an example on how to get your cache directory path:

[android-download-images-from-server-and-save-them-on-device-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103729/android-download-images-from-server-and-save-them-on-device-cache)

And this on conversion from `Drawable` to `Bitmap`:

[how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: This is for a bitmap. What about from a Drawable? See my code.

Comment: @Ethan Allen. Convert the Drawable to a Bitmap. See edited answer.

Comment: Yep, just found it: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); - Thanks for the help!