# Thread in loading image in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am using thread to load the image in my getview() of my BaseAdapter class.But the image is not loading properly..When i scroll listview images are changing..Same image is coming for some positions..Help me solve this.

This is my getview code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

//       View listView = convertView;
        Position=position;
         ViewHolder holder;

         Thread thread = new Thread()
         {
             public void run() 
             {
                  bitmap=   DownloadImage(
                         kickerimage[Position] );       

             }
         };
         thread.start();
//  Bitmap bitmap=  DownloadImage(
//               kickerimage[position] );       

         if (convertView   == null) 
            {
                //this should only ever run if you do not get a view back            
             LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) contxt
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelistrow, null); 

             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.icon);


             holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.name_label);
             convertView.setTag(holder);            
            }

         else
                    { 
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();         
                     }
//       





         holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
////         items=itemsarray[position];
         holder.text.setText(itemsarray[position]);

return convertview
}
```

Comment: Put your thread into if else block

Comment: use Asynctask instead of Thread For Better Performance of your App

Comment: Thanks Yahor10..I am new to this concept..Can you give some more details??

Comment: Thanks Dixit Patel..Can you give some more details..

Answer (score 1):

The lazy loading of images in `ListView` is what you are looking for the links below might help you out. Also try searching google for lazy loading images in android, there might be a lot of results which might help you out.

1. [Android, how to lazy load images from url and persistently cache them in gallery widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125754/android-how-to-lazy-load-images-from-url-and-persistently-cache-them-in-gallery)
2. [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: Thanks lalith..I gone through a lots of tutorial for lazy loading but i can't understand the coding..There are lots of line of code..SO only i decided to use thread.Anyway i will try for your link..

Comment: @Subburaj no need to understand code at 1st try, once you are using it and experimenting, you will come to know the mechanism of this kind of lazy loading logic.

Comment: Threading logic is more difficult to implement by yourself than just use the code thats already there, Work reverse to understand the logic. Guess my answer solved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks Paresh Mayani..I have tried once..But in my emulator the images are loading(Android 2.1) but in my device its not loading(Android 2.3.4)..Why this is happening??.

Comment: The link `LazyList` works for both emulator and device, I've tried and tested it. Upvote and accept the answer if your question is answered.

Comment: lalith....I have tried once..But in my emulator the images are loading(Android 2.1) but in my device its not loading(Android 2.3.4)..Why this is happening??

Comment: check if your device is connected to internet.