# Geoserver/google_maps/Android saving cache

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, geoserver, mbtiles

My application is getting tiles from geoserver and displaying it over a google map.
I would like to know if it is possible to save those tiles so i can access them offline ?? 
Ps: I downloaded an mbtiles file but it's locally accessed, when data changes in geoserver, this file keeps the old informations. 
I want to have a dynamic solution, please any help ?? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the tiles where ever you like (subject to copyright and licensing issues). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125754/android-how-to-lazy-load-images-from-url-and-persistently-cache-them-in-gallery) has some Android solutions.

Usually you would just strip off the host and port from the url and save the image to "disk", then when a tile is requested you first check the cache, if there is an image check it's age, and either serve that tile or fetch a new tile.